# zoom level and annotation on MKMapView with MKPolyLine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have 3 MKPolyLine that is drawn on the MKMapView. How do I zoom to the best maximum possible showing those three routes?
I know that I have to use the setRegion method. However I am confused on how to calculate the MKCoordinateRegion and the MKCoordinateSpan.
Can someone help me out? Thanks

Also another question is how can I show an annotation at the middle of the MKPolyLine (i.e: the middle of the route)??

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

- Find the maximum and minimum latitude and longitude values in all of your polylines. Then do:

```
CLLocationDegrees deltaLat = maxLat-minLat;

CLLocationDegrees deltaLong = maxLong-minLong;

CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(deltaLat/2, deltaLong/2);

MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(deltaLat, deltaLong);  

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoord, span);

[mapView setRegion : region animated : YES];
```

Comment: how about putting the annotation at the middle of the route?

Comment: To achieve this you'll first need to calculate the total route length, divide by 2 (to get the half-way distance) and find a point on your polyline that is exactly half-way distance from your start-point.  

Take a look at [CoreLocationUtils](https://github.com/100grams/CoreLocationUtils) for calculating distances etc.

Comment: Calculating the total route length is quite basic stuff, but finding the middle point along a MKPolyline (which might only be made of a start and end point) seems like the hard part to me. CoreLocationUtils doesn't help with that either.